# What does ⌘-L do in XCode?

Tags: xcode

Sometimes in XCode I hit ⌘-L by accident, and I get a white box with a cursor in the middle of my screen.

[image: xcode with jump option]

I did some poking around and it's supposed to **Jump in '[file].m'**

No matter what I type, it never jumps to any particular function or file in Xcode. It basically just sits there and lets me type in it.

How is this feature supposed to be used? From what I've read in the docs, it should allow me to quickly navigate (or jump!) to specific parts of my code. But it doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Am I misunderstanding this feature, or is there something not working in my copy of XCode?

Comment: I suppose it jumps to a line specified by number. You probably can use line/character numbers to go to specified character in specified line.

Comment: More importantly, what key combo did you use to type the cmd character?

Comment: @myron lol.. copy and paste from wikipedia

Comment: The UTF-8 unicode is \u2318.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a shortcut to jump to a specific line number. Press `⌘-L`, enter a line number, then press `ENTER`.

[image]

Comment: After years of using Xcode, I know realize that I've never taken even 5 minutes to examine this 'Navigate' menu; it's full of useful commands.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> allows you to type a line number and Xcode will jump to that line. Enter the line number and then <kbd>enter</kbd>.